# Замена строки в Excel с помощью Python

Tags: python, excel, замена

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью Python найти и заменить строку в Excel?

например: есть строка "MainMenuStart" ,как её заменить на "СтартОсновногоМеню"?

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть библиотеку xlrd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52277175/5741205